# Try to do a basic Performance Attribution analysis using the "pa" package in R

Tags: r, attribution

I loaded a package called "`pa`" in R trying to do some basic performance attribution analysis for my portfolio, the pa package comes with its own data frame, namely "year"

I tried the data (year) in the console line, it works

[image: year data]

My problem.....

I tried to create/import a CSV file and I call it `Rtestcsv` (with all my holding and Bloomberg code)

[image: Rtestcsv]

I tried to type `[data (Rtestcsv)]` in the console, error msg pops up and said the file is not found, why?

is it true the  "`pa`" package created by Yang Lu can only apply to his own data frame?

In order to use the "pa" package performance simple analysis, what should i have to do with my own data frame? coz it seems the CSV file has been successfully imported and appeared in the top right-hand R environment

[image: R environment]

I would  appreciate if someone could shed me some insights to handle my issue as I am new to R

Answer (score 0):

The `data()` function is mainly used to import preexisting data sets from provided package and not your own csvs or xlsx files, etc. To import your own data you can use the `read.csv()` function. However, I would recommend the `read_csv()` function from the readr package as it's much faster. (Make sure you install it first)

```
library(readr)
rtestcsv <- read_csv("/path/to/file.csv")
```

The slashes can be omitted if the file is in your working directory. You should be able access your data frame as a variable. Once it's in your environment you should be able to do with it as you please. As for how you should further wrangle your data frame, that all depends on what kind of analysis you plan on doing and what functions you want to use.